# wpf devexpress gridcontrol with radiobutton, pass IsEnabled binding to celltemplate

Tags: wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a Gridcolumn like this:

```
<dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding OrderTyp, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                Header="Order" 
                                Visible="{Binding IsOrderToMe}"
                                Width="60"
                                IsEnabled="{Binding StatusHandled, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBooleanConverter}}"
                                CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsOrderTyp}"/>
```

My celltemplate looks like this:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="IsOrderTyp">
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{styles:GridCellValueBinding 
                            Converter={StaticResource ECompare}, 
                            ConverterParameter={x:Static enums:OrderTypIdEnum.ORDER}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 IsEnabled="{Binding ????????????}"
                 Style="{StaticResource GridRadioButtonStyle}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
```

how do I get the binding for IsEnabled from the gridcolumn in my celltemplate?

Comment: Check out [TemplateBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: @dontbyteme I tried:
IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding Property=dxg:GridColumn.ReadOnly, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBooleanConverter}}"
IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsEnabled}"
IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsEnabled}"
IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=dxg:GridColumn}, Path=IsEnabled}"
Nothing worked.